# When using pytesseract OSD, file not found error but for a seemingly random filename

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

When I try to use `pytesseract.image_to_osd()` with any image and with any psm mode (I use 12 but I have tried this with the others), I get this error:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\IS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tess_6f2kkuwq.osd'`

Every time I run the code the missing "file" is different, but always is in the same format:
tess_xxxxxxx.osd with the middle part being seemingly random.

What is going on here?

Full code:

```
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output
import cv2

img = "cn.png"

conf = r'--psm 12'

img = cv2.imread(img)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img = cv2.bilateralFilter(img,9,75,75)

result = pytesseract.image_to_osd(img, config=conf, output_type=Output.DICT)

print(result)
```

Comment: I had the same problem. Adding the expected output format to the start of the config string fixed it for me (Windows, Tesseract 5.0.0-alpha). Eventually this could help you also:
`pytesseract.image_to_osd(img, config='osd --psm 0')`

Props to Oliver Zendel mentioning this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45538673/pytesseract-temporary-output-files-no-such-file-or-directory-error/#answer-55340796).

Comment: This didn't solve my issue unfortunately (Ubuntu, Tesseract 3.04.01). My code looks like this:
`text = pytesseract.image_to_osd(image,config="osd --psm 0",output_type=pytesseract.Output.DICT)`
Any ideas?