# pytesseract can't find tmp files on AWS Lambda Python

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, tesseract, python-tesseract

First of, a very similar question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77476966/tesseract-osd-cant-find-files-in-tmp) but i don't have enough reputation points to comment my questions on that thread. I am sorry in advanced if this is not the correct way to handle cases like this one.

**The context:**

I have a lambda function where the handler is a docker image. The Dockerfile for this image looks like this:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9

# ... code 

RUN yum install -y tesseract

RUN curl -L -o /usr/share/tesseract/tessdata/spa.traineddata https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/main/spa.traineddata
RUN curl -L -o /usr/share/tesseract/tessdata/osd.traineddata https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/main/osd.traineddata

# ... more code  

CMD ["index.lambda_handler"]
```

**The Problem:**
I'm trying to use `image_to_osd` from pytesseract on my lambda_handler but i get the following error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tess_qizpc7u6.osd'
```

My understanding of this error so far comes from [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45538673/pytesseract-temporary-output-files-no-such-file-or-directory-error). They mention python 2.7 while I'm working with python 3.9

**I have two questions.**

- First, if the issue is caused by the pytesseract library itself (as mentioned on the other thread). How come it works fine locally but not when it is used on a different environment?
- How could I make the same "hackish changes to the pytesseract script" mentioned on the other thread.
- If possible, please help me solve this issue with an alternative way.

I have been googling this issue on different sites and trying to understand the problem the best that I can. The only solutions that I have been able to try are different values for `image_to_osd`'s config parameter as it seems that solved the issue for a few people. I have tried values like `-l spa --oem 4 --psm 7` and `--psm 0`. As mentioned, I don't know how to alter the pytesseract script so I haven't been able to try anything of that sort.